# how to detect all dollar signs in different encoding with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have a string "$ $ $ ＄ ＄", Google chrome can detect each dollar sign in the string with ctrl+F. But Javascript cannot detect all of them.

I wish to detect and replace all dollar signs in the string with Javascript . Please help.

Comment: yes, you are correct. it is my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Two</s>Four of your dollar signs are not the standard dollar sign character.

Take a **close** look at this screenshot from where I did Ctrl+F in Chrome:

[image]

See the extra padding around the last two `$` characters? They're a different character. Chrome's presumably doing some work to consider them to be the same thing (I'd bet they do the same with `a` versus `á`), but JavaScript's string functions are more picky.

(There actually seem to be five different `$` characters.)

```
var foo = '$ $ $ ＄ ＄';

foo = foo.replace('$', 'DOLLAR');
console.log(foo);
foo = foo.replace('＄', 'DOLLAR');
console.log(foo);
foo = foo.replace('＄', 'DOLLAR');
console.log(foo);
foo = foo.replace('$', 'DOLLAR');
console.log(foo);
foo = foo.replace('$', 'DOLLAR');
console.log(foo);
```

[image]

Comment: yes, i know. they are from different languages. but i wish to replace them all.

Comment: @user6949202 That seems like an important thing to mention in your question, then. You'll need to write replacement code for both characters.

Comment: sorry, the last signs failed.

Comment: learn something new every day....never would have guessed you could have 5 different versions

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the rest of the dollar signs  http://www.fileformat.info/search/google.htm?q=dollar

```js
console.log("$ $ $ ＄ ＄".replace(/[$＄﹩]/g, 0))
```

Answer (score -1):

This shall replace all occurences of dollar in mystring with 'R' :

```
let mystring = "$ $ $ ＄ ＄";
mystring = mystring.replace(/\$/g , "R");
mystring = mystring.replace(/\＄/g , "R");
console.log(mystring);
```

Comment: why are they not valid? How can you see them then?

Comment: @charlietfl Check out now.I actually copied the dollar signs separately and used them in the code.Now it works fine.